# Mysql 8.0 vs Mariadb 10.4 for low memory VPS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a vps with just 2Gb of memory and plan to just run wordpress on it and was wondering which is the best choice (Mysql 8.0 or Mariadb 10.4)?

Comment: Will you have Database + Web server + WP all in the same 2GB?  Possible, but tight.

Comment: @RickJames  Yes, That's why i was wondering about which can consume less memory in this case Mysql 8 or Mariadb 10.4

Answer (score 0):

You can run a webserver (nginx) plus PHP plus MySQL or MariaDB on a 2GB VPS. I run some of my Drupal sites on such an infrastructure on DigitalOcean, Wordpress is not very different. By the way MariaDB is a fork of MySQL.